# How to control instantiated prefabs at runtime as children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I have a game in Unity where I instantiate GameObjects every few seconds. Then in the Hierarchy, the prefabs show up in a list of them being instantiated e.g.:

```
EnemyBlue(Clone)
EnemyRed(Clone)
EnemyGreen(Clone)
EnemyBlue(Clone)
```

Which clogs up my hierarchy. My question is, is it possible to instantiate GameObjects as a child of an empty GameObject, for example:

```
Enemies // An Empty GameObject
    EnemyBlue(Clone)
    EnemyRed(Clone)
    EnemyGreen(Clone)
    EnemyBlue(Clone)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the parent of a transform like ILiveForVR mentioned, but you can also set the parent for something that already exists:

`gameObject.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Name of game object").transform;`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the parent of an object after you instantiate it: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html

So something like:`EnemyBlue.tranform.SetParent(Enemies.transform);`

Comment: Would you have to set the parent in the inspector? Or could you do a .Find to find the parent?